# Read the Tables data from the Docx files

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to read the Word Docx file and its reading fine with apache POI, but now I have a problem in reading the Docx file which has the table inside the file
Kinldy anyone please help me how to read the data from the tables inside the Document.
Kinldy find the screenshot of the document which I want to read with java.
[image]

***Have to retrieve the Highlighted data from the doc.***

```
public static void readDocxFile(String fileName){
        try {
            File file = new File(fileName);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
            XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(fis);

            List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = document.getParagraphs();

            System.out.println("Total Number of Paragraphs:: "+paragraphs.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < paragraphs.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(paragraphs.get(i).getParagraphText());
            }
            fis.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This was the Method I was using for returning the data in the pages, but not getting the data marked in yellow, but only those data are getting in output which are not mentioned inside the table in word document.

Comment: Can you consider showing us your work please?

Comment: [XWPFDocument](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html)`.getTables()` -> [XWPFTable](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTable.html)`.getRows()` -> [XWPFTableRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTableRow.html)`.getTableCells()` -> [XWPFTableCell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTableCell.html)`.getText()` or `.getParagraphs()` and then working with the paragraphs.

Answer (score 5):

```js
public class ReadTableWord {
 static String temp = "";
static String cellValue;
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  
  
  File file = new File("D:/Test111/BRD-+machine-usage+updation.docx");
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
  XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(fis);
  List<XWPFTable> tables = doc.getTables();
 
  for (XWPFTable table : tables) {
   for (XWPFTableRow row : table.getRows()) {
    for (XWPFTableCell cell : row.getTableCells()) {
     System.out.println(cell.getText());
     String sFieldValue = cell.getText();
     if (sFieldValue.matches("Whatever you want to match with the string") || sFieldValue.matches("Approved")) {
      System.out.println("The match as per the Document is True");
     }
//     System.out.println("\t");
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
   }
  }
  
 }

}
```

---

***This is the Correct answer for this.***

---