# Java - Microsoft Word get column value in table (right side)

Tags: java, apache-poi, aspose

Currently, I would like to create a java program to read the microsoft word.
There is a table in the microsoft and I would like to read the value

Where it need to search for the word and then get the value on the right side.

[image]

For example, when I pass in parameter as "Field1", it will return with result "AAAAAA".
If I pass in as "Field3", it will return with "CCCCCC".

How can I archive that?
If there is any library that can help to do that?

Comment: maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102511/how-read-doc-or-docx-file-in-java

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44016335/read-the-tables-data-from-the-docx-files/44061001 this could also help

Comment: You should do some research first and then ask about a more specific problem and show us what you have done so far.

Comment: Both libraries, `apache poi` as well as `aspose`, can do this. Choose one, read the documentation, start coding and come back with a concrete question and a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you are stuck.